# SQLのクエリについて（サブクエリ、where句）

Tags: sql

SQL上のDBにuser, audit, changelogという3つのテーブルがあります。
カラムは以下のとおりです。

[user]
id, email, date

[audit]
user_id, difference_id, date

[changelog]
difference_id, log, year, month, date

※user.idとaudit.user_idは共通したデータです

changelog.difference_idからuser.emailを索引したいのですが、where句は必ず「where date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ‘%Y%m%d’)」を含め、結果を日付で絞って返させたいです。
クエリを1つにまとめたいのですが、サブクエリをどのように記述すればよいかわかりません。（具体的には、上記のwhereに複数条件が入るかつサブサブクエリを使うという状況に混乱しています）

要するに、下記2つのクエリをまとめたうえで、日付が本日（動的）のものを出したいということです。
select user_id
from audit
where changelog.difference_id = ‘{{9fjei347fyw83926r}}’
→user_id = 1007 が返る

select email
from user
inner join audit on id = user_id
where user_id = ‘{{1007}}’

何分初心者なもので、意味不明な箇所もあるかと思いますが、できるだけ優しく教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「与えられた `difference_id` から `changelog` テーブルのレコードを見つけて、それに関連付けられている `user` テーブルのレコードの `email` を見たい」および「`changelog` テーブルのレコードは `year`、`month`、`date` でも絞り込みたい」ということであれば以下のようなクエリで見つけられます。サブクエリは不要です。

```
select
    changelog.difference_id
    , user.email
from
    changelog
    inner join audit on changelog.difference_id = audit.difference_id
    inner join user on audit.user_id = user.id
where
    changelog.difference_id = ここに調べたいIDを入れる
    and changelog.year = "2022" and changelog.month = "06" and changelog.date = "17"
```

> where句は必ず「where date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ‘%Y%m%d’)」を含め、結果を日付で絞って返させたいです。

質問文のこの部分の解釈があっているか自信がありません。もしこういうことでなければ、サンプルのデータとサンプルの条件を元にどのような結果を望んでいるかの例があると分かりやすいです。

特に、`difference_id` が分かっているのであればそれだけで `changelog` テーブルのレコードが見つけられるので、更に日付で絞り込む意図がよく分かりませんでした。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

なるほど、inner joinを続ければいいのですね。
where句の指定は、動的に「今日」の日付で検索したいからなのですが、そうすると

where changelog.difference_id = ここに調べたいIDを入れる
and date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ‘%Y%m%d’)

みたいなかんじでOKってことになるでしょうか…！

Comment: @かもなんばん `date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ‘%Y%m%d’)` 単体では条件式になっていないのでこれでは判別できません。year, month, date カラムと比較することもできますが、それをやったとしても結局 `difference_id` で絞り込んでいるので、なぜ日付で絞り込みたいのかが謎でした。

Comment: うう…なるほど…。
実際のテーブル名などの記載を控える目的で色々と実際の状況と変えて質問してしまったので、混乱させてしまいましたね…本当に申し訳ないです。

ただ、教えていただいたことは私にとってたいへん勉強になりましたので、今一度考えなおしてみて、またわからなくなりましたら質問をポストさせていただきます…！

お手数をおかけしました。
そしてありがとうございました！